# Ranking a dynamic table range by size

Tags: vba, excel

I have a dynamic table range of certain values (amounts). These amounts are generated into the table through a macro I've created.

[image]

**What I want to do: Rank these amounts into the empty column by number.**
eg. the cell in Column G next to 89k would be ranked as 1, one next to 77k would be 2 etc.

I also already have other functions defined, which I'm not going to explain here for readability reasons, but all you need to know: there are two variables obtained through functions

> 1. tbl_first = (int) Index of the ListRow of the first table item (so in this case it would be the row with 89k = 1st row so in this example 1)
> 2. tbl_last = (int) same as above, but indexes the last row (77k) in this example as 7

so my code is the following

```
' sets the tbl variable to the red table in the picture
Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = Sheets("Summary").ListObjects("time_top") 

Dim pos As Integer, diff as integer
diff = tbl_last - tbl_first
For j = tbl_first To tbl_last ' loops through all the added rows
  For n = 1 to diff' indexing for the large function
     ' index the pos through the excel large function for our values (should return the k-th position from the largest value)
     pos = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(Range(Cells(tbl_first, 6), Cells(tbl_last, 6)), n) 

     With tbl.ListRows(1)
       .Range(j, 6) = pos ' add the value to the column G to the right
     End With
 Next n
Next j
```

So the expected result would look like this:

[image]

I also keep getting the following error, which is caused by me incorrectly assigning the `pos` value.

[image]

Either way, probably multiple of things wrong here and much more elegant solution is out there, that just didn't hit me yet.

Answer (score 0):

Think you need Rank (watch out for equal ranks). Large returns the nth largest value of a set.

Here is a simple example on a two column table which perhaps you can adapt. The rank is added in the second column.

[image]

```
Sub xx()

Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = Sheets("Summary").ListObjects("time_top")

Dim r As Range

For Each r In tbl.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange
    r.Offset(, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Rank(r, tbl.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange)
Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey, few things. Tried your example, but unfortunately doesn't work either, for various reasons `.Rank` is defined as `Rank([arg1 DOUBLE], [arg2 Range], [arg 3])` regardless I was able to intuitevely fix thay myself, but I still keep getting the `> unable to get Rank property in WorksheetFunction class` error

Comment: Rank does work. Perhaps not all of your values are numeric.

Comment: Did you try compiling and running your code? I doubt it will run your code with .Rank taking first argument as a range instead of double. 

*(At least I couldn't run it that way).*

Comment: I wouldn't have posted it if it didnt work - I suggest you re-read guidance on Rank. "At least I couldn't run it that way" - clearly there is an issue with your data.